# How to resolve "minTime in Android 2.3.4 not working" error

Tags: android, gps

Comic... I've tested in an `android 1.6` and `2.3.3` a very simple gps location... with basically this:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, listener);
```

I've tested in both [1.6 and 2.3.3] with the 10 seconds waiting for the notifiers [showing a toast at `onLocationChanged`...], But strangely in an `2.3.4` version of `android` it simply ignores the `minTime` [does not matter if it is 10000 or 120000] it keep looking for changes all the time...

Anyone with this problem? Maybe it is not in the 2.3.4 the problem but anyone else had this problem too?

Answer (score 1):

This is working as documented. `minTime` is a suggestion, not a rule. Quoting the documentation:

> This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.

Comment: But i was trying to understand why it simply ignores it. It is not even an hint... it is completely ignored. Using it as 0 or as 200000 results in the same. And it is an native resource to use so i supose it should work at least as a hint[some value close to the one specified] in every single android system...